# How does this thing work this way,just explain

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
Display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Blocky")

red = (157, 139, 215)
black = (0,0,0)

Display.fill(red)
pygame.draw.rect(Display,black,(400,300,200,80))

pygame.display.update()

excape = False

while not excape:
    for dork in pygame.event.get():
        print (dork)
```

[[image: Result]

Works correctly But When I copy and paste red to pygame.draw under the update function it doesn't work.. Why doesn't ?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you call `pygame.draw.rect` after `pygame.display.update`. `pygame.display.update` is responsible to render your surface from memory to your computer's display. You drew your rect to the surface, but never call `update` to refresh the display

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What happens when you make the change?

Comment: I mean after pasting the code under the update function, the results aren't the same, why doesn't it work if i put those code under the update function.. that's why i said "Doesn't work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PyGame` draws in buffer in memory and [updata()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) / [flip()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) sends data from this buffer to video card which will display it on monitor.

It is popular method for problem with flicking screen and it is called [Double Buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics)

If you draw after `update()` then it will be not send to video card.

BTW: In normal game you draw and use `update()` in `while` loop so it doesn't make problem.

Answer (score 2):

Because `(157, 139, 215)` is not the color red. It's the same purple color as your background.

Replace it with `red = (255, 0, 0)`

and set the background display to a different fill color.

So something like this:

```
purple = (157, 139, 215)
red = (255, 0, 0)
black = (0,0,0)

Display.fill(purple)
pygame.draw.rect(Display,red,(400,300,200,80))
```

Comment: I meant copying the code from red-pygame.draw and then pasting it under update,when i do this the results aren't the same , now my questions is why?

Comment: @RuhanUR you already get answer in @Mirac7 comment. PyGame draws in buffer and `updata()/flip()` send data from buffer to video card which will display it on monitor. It is popular method for problem with flicking screen and it is called [double-buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics) If you draw after `update()` then it will be not send to video card.